# Get rid of "connection refused" error in bash script

Tags: bash, tcp, exec, set

I have this line:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9091 > /dev/null 2>&1 ||  { PORT_IS_FREE="yes"; };
```

which is checking if port 9091 is available.
If a connection cannot be made, then I get this error:

```
my-script: connect: Connection refused
my-script: line 6: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9091: Connection refused
```

of course, this error is not bad news, it means the port is free. How can I prevent the error trace from being logged? I tried sending stdout/stderr to /dev/null, but apparently that's not doing the trick.

Bonus:

I have `set -e` at the top the script - everything will halt if the connection is refused - how can I prevent that halt, if an error is expected on a particular line like the one above?

So I have two goals:

1. Get rid of the error message, because it's expected and I don't need my library users to see it.
2. Ignore the error as it's expected, and I still want to use set -e, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

To keep using `set -e` but still allow a known error, use this incantation:

```
/bin/false || :
```

This uses the `||` operator to 'consume' the error so that it is deemed nonfatal to an environment in which `set -e` is active.

You're already using `2>/dev/null` to suppress standard error, so are you sure the error is coming from the line you cite here?  Also, rather than using `exec`, I propose as a more readable alternative:

```
if ! nc -z localhost 9091 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
    port_free="yes"
fi
```

Since the return code of `nc` is checked by the `if` statement, this is also safe after `set -e`.

Comment: thanks, I am not sure how to use the incantation in the context of the script above...my guess is `/bin/false || exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9091 > /dev/null 2>&1` is that right? I think using netcat like you have is prob better, yes.

Comment: I am pretty certain 1> is equaivalent to >, and I find the latter much more readable.

Comment: if I use `set -e` with the `nc` command you have in the if statement it will conk out, so I need to use /bin/false before the nc command.

Comment: I get /bin/false: No such file or directory....hmmm

Comment: lol, whoops I forgot I am on Mac right now...I do need something x-platform though

Comment: @AlexanderMills he meant : `code which ends up returning non zero || :` (false is just an exemple of a code returning non-zero)

Comment: @AlexanderMills, @Olivier Dulac: AlexanderMills is already using the "incantation" in the original example. Since the variable assignment is going to exit with `0`, there will be no problem with `set -e`.
@DopeGhoti: The redirection isn't proper, the error is coming from when the shell tries to open a socket.

Answer (score 2):

To properly redirect both the error and output streams to /dev/null, thereby suppressing the error message, you need to group the whole exec command:

`{ exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9091; } > /dev/null 2>&1 || PORT_IS_FREE="yes"`

`exec` is a shell builtin, so it is hard to predict for me how it will behave, however I assume that even though it is able to treat `<` and `>` specially, the whole operation is still carried out in several steps, the streams of only the last of which get redirected.
Someone who knows more about the workings of `exec` might be able to shed some light on this.

EDIT: I do not know why you needed brace-grouping for your variable assignment since it's a single command, but you can still use braces in conjunction with my examples if you want to, instead of the bare assignment I used.

As for ignoring the error, you could terminate the command after the redirection with `;`instead of using its exit status via `||` :

`{ exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9091; } > /dev/null 2>&1 ; PORT_IS_FREE="yes"`

Of course, in this case, there is the issue that you will not be able to catch any other error either. I just tried and the exit status is 1 after the error in question happens. If other codes are returned on different errors (which I doubt actually, since 1 is a very generic error code), you could test for 1.
EDIT: This solution also comes with the benefit of not exiting when code 1 is returned after the `exec`, when `set -e` is used:

`{ exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9091; } > /dev/null 2>&1 || [ "$?" = 1 ] && PORT_IS_FREE="yes"`

Otherwise, you might use `grep` to try and match the error message, which is more reliable in my opinion:

```
socketOpenOutput="$({ exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9091; } 2>&1`)"
socketOpenErrorCode="$?"
if [ "$socketOpenErrorCode" != 0 ]; then
    if ! echo "$socketOpenOutput" | grep 'connect\s*:\s*Connection refused' >/dev/null; then
        echo "An unexpected error happened when opening the socket!"
        exit 1
    fi
fi

PORT_IS_FREE="yes"
```

This one, however, does not work well with `set -e` .

Comment: Here is an example of how I was able to integrate this solution into an if statement;